# In Bigquery, How to Call Previous & Current Month Value inside YYYYmmdd format

Tags: google-bigquery

How to Call Previous & Current Month Value  inside  `YYYYmmdd` format

```
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '2022[CallPreviousMonthValue]01' AND '2022[CallCurrentMonthValue]10'
```

Output Expected:

```
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '2022**02**01' AND '2022**03**10'
```

The Table should through the result from `01-FEb-2022` Till `10-Mar-2022`

Pls. Help

Comment: does it answer your question, @RamakrishnanM?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parse_date()`, `date_sub()` and `date_add()` to achieve it as following:

```sql
select date_sub(parse_date('%Y%m%d',"20220201"), INTERVAL 1 month) previous,
 date_add(parse_date('%Y%m%d',"20220201"), INTERVAL 1 month) next
```

Result:
[image]